# adding a combo box at run time - JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery

i have added html elements at run time using append
Code:

```
function addFormField() {       
    $("#inputss").append("<strong>asif</strong>"); }
```

but how can i add a select element at run time that looks like this..

PHP Code:

```
<select name="pre_req"  id="pre_req" class="inputs"  
value=<? if($this->uri->segment(2)=='update') echo $results['pre_req']?>> 

<option value='None'>None</option>             

<? foreach($combo1 as $row)
echo "<option value=$row[sub_name]>$row[sub_name</option>";
?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have client-side (ie. JavaScript code) that adds an HTML element you obviously cannot have PHP code there. You would need to have a web page written in PHP that returns the HTML you want for the element you want and then insert that element using jQuery. jQuery has a really handy method for this [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), but you need to create an element first. Eg.

```
 $("#inputss").append("<div id='placeholder'></div>");
 $("#placeholder").load('someAjaxService.php')
```

Comment: thnks..i did this..

$select="<p><select name=pre_req  id=pre_req class=inputs><option value=None>None</option>";
       foreach($combo1 as $row)
       $select.= "<option value=$row[sub_name]>$row[sub_name]</option>";
      $select.="</select></p>";

and then

onClick="addFormField('<?=$select?>')

its working now